# Using spark/scala, I use saveAsTextFile() to HDFS, but hiveql("select count(*) from...) return 0

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

- I created external table as follows...

  `hive -e "create external table temp_db.temp_table (a char(10), b int) PARTITIONED BY (PART_DATE VARCHAR(10)) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/work/temp_db/temp_table'"`
- And I use saveAsTextFile() with scala in IntelliJ IDEA as follows...
  `itemsRdd.map(_.makeTsv).saveAsTextFile("hdfs://work/temp_db/temp_table/2016/07/19")`
- So the file(fields terminated by '\t') was in the `/work/temp_db/temp_table/2016/07/19. 
  hadoop fs -ls /work/temp_db/temp_table/2016/07/19/part-00000 <- data file..`
- But, I checked with hiveql, there are no datas as follows.
  `hive -e "select count(*) from temp_db.temp_table" -> 0.
  hive -e "select * from temp_db.temp_table limit 5" -> 0 rows fetched.`
- Help me what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are saving at wrong location from spark. Partition dir name follows `part_col_name=part_value`.

*In Spark: save file at directory `part_date=2016%2F07%2F19` under `temp_table` dir*

```
itemsRdd.map(_.makeTsv)
.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://work/temp_db/temp_table/part_date=2016%2F07%2F19")
```

*add partitions: You will need to add partition that should update hive table's metadata (partition dir we have created from spark as hive expected `key=value` format)*

`alter table temp_table add partition (PART_DATE='2016/07/19');`

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/temp_table/part*|awk '{print $NF}'
/user/hive/warehouse/temp_table/part_date=2016%2F07%2F19/part-00000
/user/hive/warehouse/temp_table/part_date=2016-07-19/part-00000
```

*query partitioned data:*

```
hive> alter table temp_table add partition (PART_DATE='2016/07/19');
OK
Time taken: 0.16 seconds
hive> select * from temp_table where PART_DATE='2016/07/19';
OK
test1       123 2016/07/19
Time taken: 0.219 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select * from temp_table;
OK
test1       123 2016/07/19
test1       123 2016-07-19
Time taken: 0.199 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

For Everyday process: you can run saprk job like this - just add partitions right after `saveAsTextFile()`, aslo note the `s` in `alter` statement. it is need to pass variable in hive sql from spark:

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
vat date = format.format(new java.util.Date())

itemsRDD.saveAsTextFile("/user/hive/warehouse/temp_table/part=$date")

val hive = new HiveContext(sc)                                                            
hive.sql(s"alter table temp_table add partition (PART_DATE='$date')")
```

***NOTE:*** Add partition after saving the file or else spark will throw directory already exist exception as hive creates dir (if not exist) when adding partition.

Comment: Thank you!!! 
I plan to manage hdfs directory as follows...
".../temp_table/2016/07/19"
".../temp_table/2016/07/20"
...
...
So... Should I command the clause "alter table temp_table add partition (part_date= ....)" everyday?

Comment: And... I want hide the name, "part_date".
So, there is I want... ".../temp_table/2016/07/19"(years/months/days, each directory), Not ".../temp_table/part_date=2016%2F07%2F19".
Thank you!!

Comment: for daily load you can create spark job( see updated answer). for renaming the partition directory you use below command but this is mostly to change the partition value NOT removing key from dir name - it will mess up hive metadata - I strongly advice NOT to experiment it! I know it will never work but here is a command - `ALTER TABLE table_name [PARTITION partition_spec] SET LOCATION "new location";`

Comment: BigDataLearner!! Thank you!!!!!!! Now my project is operating very well.!!